# Minimum three variable expression $\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{(a+b+c)^3|(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)|}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

If $a,b,c \ge 0$ are distinct real numbers, find the minimum value of

$$\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3}{(a+b+c)^3|(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)|}$$

What I did: I used $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq \frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)^2$, but no success. A friend of mine said the minimum happens when one of the variables is $0$, but I don't really understand why or how to prove this.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an easy question. It can be rephrased as:

> Find the best constant $k$ such that the inequality
>
> $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\geq k(a+b+c)^3|(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)|$$
>
> holds for any non-negative real numbers $a,b$ and $c$.

The product $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ is cyclic, but in the module the inequality becomes symmetric, so we can assume that $a\leq b \leq c$. In this case, we want to find the best $k$ such that:

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\geq k(a+b+c)^3(c-a)(c-b)(b-a)$$

If we fix $b$ and $c$, the product $(c-a)(c-b)(b-a)$ is maximized when $a=0$. So let's set $a=0$ and $c=bt$ with $t> 1$ to see what happens. Then:

$$(b^2+b^2t^2)^3\geq k(b+bt)^3bt(bt-b)b$$

or

$$k\leq \frac{(t^2+1)^3}{t(t-1)(t+1)^3}$$

Now, define $f:(1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$

$$f(t)=\frac{(t^2+1)^3}{t(t-1)(t+1)^3}$$

The first derivative is

$$f'(t)=\frac{(t^2+1)^3(t^4+2t^3-10t^2+2t+1)}{t^2(t-1)^2(t+1)^4}$$

The fourth degree polynomial has four real roots:

$$t_{1,2}= \frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{13}\pm \sqrt{10-2\sqrt{13}}),\ t_{3,4}=\frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{13}\pm \sqrt{10+2\sqrt{13}})$$

Out of these, only $t_1=\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{13}+\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{13}}) > 1$ (it lies in $f$'s domain) and we can check that this is a local minima. Therefore:

$$k=\min_{t > 1} f(t)=f(t_1)=\frac{1}{9}\sqrt{3522-858\sqrt{13}}\approx 2.29985776707797...$$

And indeed, we can check in the initial inequality that if we set $(a,b,c)=(0,1,t_1)$, we get that the minimum value is $f(t_1)$.

Now we can start the actual proof of the inequality. We have to show that:

$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3 \geq \frac{(t_1^2+1)^3}{t_1(t_1-1)(t_1+1)^3}(a+b+c)^3(c-b)(c-a)(b-a)$$

Since $a^2 \geq 0$, it is enough to show that:

$$(b^2+c^2)^3 \geq \frac{(t_1^2+1)^3}{t_1(t_1-1)(t_1+1)^3}(a+b+c)^3(c-b)(c-a)(b-a)$$

Using AM-GM, we get:

$$\left(\frac{a+b+c}{t_1+1}\right)^3\cdot \frac{c-b}{t_1-1}\cdot \frac{c-a}{t_1}\cdot (b-a) \leq \frac{1}{6^6} \left(\frac{3(a+b+c)}{t_1+1}+\frac{c-b}{t_1-1}+\frac{c-a}{t_1}+b-a\right)^6$$

Thus, it's enough to show that:

$$b^2+c^2\geq \frac{t_1^2+1}{36}\left(\frac{3(a+b+c)}{t_1+1}+\frac{c-b}{t_1-1}+\frac{c-a}{t_1}+b-a\right)^2$$

Inside the parantheses, the coefficient of $a$ is

$$\frac{t_1-1-t_1^2}{t_1(t_1+1)} < 0$$

so we can ignore it altogether. Therefore, it remains to prove:

$$b^2+c^2\geq \frac{t_1^2+1}{36}\left(\frac{3(b+c)}{t_1+1}+\frac{c-b}{t_1-1}+\frac{c}{t_1}+b\right)^2$$

or

$$36(b^2+c^2)\geq \frac{t_1^2+1}{[t_1(t_1-1)(t_1+1)]^2}\left[(t_1^3+2t_1^2-5t_1)b+(5t_1^2-2t_1-1)c\right]^2$$

This follows from Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\left[(t_1^3+2t_1^2-5t)b+(5t_1^2-2t_1-1)c\right]^2\leq \left[(t_1^3+2t_1^2-5t_1)^2+(5t_1^2-2t_1-1)^2\right](b^2+c^2)$$

and we can check that:

$$\frac{(t_1^2+1)\left[(t_1^3+2t_1^2-5t_1)^2+(5t_1^2-2t_1-1)^2\right]}{[t_1(t_1-1)(t_1+1)]^2}=36$$

completing the proof. Equality occurs when $(a:b:c) = (0:1:t_1)$ up to any cyclic permutation.

*Note*: I chose to write $t_1$ instead of the actual value in the entire proof, because the numbers are ugly up until the last equality.

Comment: "If we fix $b$ and $c$, the product $(c−a)(c−b)(b−a)$ is maximized when $a=0$", however, $(a+b+c)$ is minimized when $a=0$?

Comment: @RiverLi, I ignored $(a+b+c)^3$. This is not an argument for proving the inequality, but for when the fraction might reach the minimum (we need to find the equality case). The actual proof is in progress :)

Comment: OK, I see, it is just something behind a proof.

Comment: @RiverLi, I completed it now. You can check it out :)

Comment: (+1) The actual proof part is nice.

Comment: @RiverLi, Thanks, it's a non-calculus proof that would be impossible to find without calculus... I think we can prove many inequalities with $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$ in this way.

Comment: Sometimes, the actual proof is elementary although the thinking process is complicated.

Answer (score 5):

Your friend was right!

Indeed, we can assume that $a<b<c$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$(a+b+c)^3(c-a)(c-b)(b-a)\leq bc(c-b)(b+c)^3$$ or
$$a((b+c)(b^3+c^3)+(b+c)(2b^2+bc+2c^2)a-bca^2-2(b+c)a^3-a^4)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Also, $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\geq(b^2+c^2)^3$$ and after assuming $c=xb$ it's enough to find $$\min_{x>1}\frac{(x^2+1)^3}{(x+1)^3(x-1)x},$$ The rest is smooth.

Comment: It is a  nice solution.